# Quantiling reps performance

Tags: r

This is a simple question from an R rookie.
I need to quantile reps performance based on annual sales but the data is provided in quarterly fashion.
Can someone help me optimize the code.

```
Rep Quarter Sales
1 100 1 25
2 100 2 32
3 100 3 40
4 100 4 52
5 101 1 40
6 101 2 23
7 101 3 37
8 101 4 61
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to get yearly sums of hte data rather than "quantiling" them. "Quantile" has a specific statistical meaning and you are not using in in a manner that suggest you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

This is really guessing, because your question is way too vague - but it sounds like you could use `aggregate`.

```
set.seed(1)
example <- data.frame(Rep=rep(100:104,each=4),
                      Quarter=rep(1:4,5),
                      Sales=sample(100,20,replace=TRUE))

> head(example)
  Rep Quarter Sales
1 100       1    27
2 100       2    38
3 100       3    58
4 100       4    91
5 101       1    21
6 101       2    90


> aggregate(example$Sales,by=list(Rep=example$Rep),summary)
  Rep x.Min. x.1st Qu. x.Median x.Mean x.3rd Qu. x.Max.
1 100  27.00     35.25    48.00  53.50     66.25  91.00
2 101  21.00     55.50    78.50  68.25     91.25  95.00
3 102   7.00     15.25    19.50  27.25     31.50  63.00
4 103  39.00     47.25    59.50  58.75     71.00  77.00
5 104  39.00     63.75    75.00  72.25     83.50 100.00
```

Or using the formula method (thanks @Ferdinand):

```
> aggregate(Sales ~ Rep,summary,data=example)
  Rep Sales.Min. Sales.1st Qu. Sales.Median Sales.Mean Sales.3rd Qu. Sales.Max.
1 100      27.00         35.25        48.00      53.50         66.25      91.00
2 101      21.00         55.50        78.50      68.25         91.25      95.00
3 102       7.00         15.25        19.50      27.25         31.50      63.00
4 103      39.00         47.25        59.50      58.75         71.00      77.00
5 104      39.00         63.75        75.00      72.25         83.50     100.00
```

You can also plot the data very easily using `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(example$Sales~example$Rep)
```

[image]